How to algebraically "decouple" a pair of linear equations without finding eigenvectors?
Consider the following linear functions:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
f_x(x,y) &= 2x + y \\
f_y(x,y) &= x + 2y 
\end{aligned} 
\right.
$$
This is equivalent to the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
We can diagonalize this matrix:
$$ 
A = PDP^{-1} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -0.5 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix}
$$
So $D$ in this case represents:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
g_x(x,y) &= x \\
g_y(x,y) &= 3y 
\end{aligned} 
\right.
$$
In essence, using $P$ we found a new basis for $A$ such that the linear functions it represents become decoupled and only depend on one input.
This diagonalization approach is always taught by finding the eigenstuff of the matrix $A$, but is there a way to algebraically do a change of variables to get the 'decoupled' functions $g_x, g_y$ without computing eigenstuff or determinants or anything involving linear algebra? For example, algebraically finding a new set of input coordinates $x = ax_2 + by_2$, etc.?

By inspection of matrix $P$, an appropriate change of variables should be $u=x+y,v=y-x$.

I used a particularly nice matrix here and I already gave the answer by showing P, but how would you find this change of variables in general without computing eigenstuff? Or is it even possible?

At least for a Hermitian operator, the change in basis implies a set of eigenvectors (their components make up the change of basis matrix). Once you have the eigenvectors the eigenvalues are easy to find. So even if you found some way to get the change of basis without diagonalizing, you would effectively have diagonalized anyway.

Finding the eigenvectors is precisely the same thing as changing coordinates via a substitution of variables that decouples the ODEs. I'm not sure what you mean by "... without computing eigenstuff ..."

For general cases, may I ask why you're bothered with "computing eigenstuff or determinants or anything involving linear algebra"?

I am not bothered actually, I am just trying to get a deeper understanding of these things at the algebra level.

You seem to be i using the term “algebra” in the US high school sense, because otherwise linear algebra certainly is algebra, isn’t it?

Yes linear algebra is algebra, I don't know how else to explain it, I just want to avoid use of matrices and stick with algebraic manipulations of equations.

In general what you describe(writing a new set of input coordinates $x=ax_2+by_2$, $y=cx_2+dy_2$) is similar to finding an eigenbasis(but, if you only want to "decouple", a bit more general), but yes it can be done algebraicaly for small systems.
For example in your case by subsituting this experssions into you equations we get:
\begin{align}
(2a+c)\cdot x_2 + (2b+d)\cdot y_2 = f(x_2,y_2) \\
(a+2c)\cdot x_2 + (b+2d)\cdot y_2 = g(x_2,y_2)
\end{align}
If we want to avoid dependence on $y_2$ in the first equation we take $d=-2b$ and plug in into the second equation:
\begin{align}
(a+2c)\cdot x_2 + (b-4b)\cdot y_2 &= (a+2c)\cdot x_2 -(3b)\cdot y_2 \\
&= g(x_2,y_2)
\end{align}
Now to avoid dependence on $x_2$ in the second equation, take $a=-2c$, so we get new equations:
\begin{align}
-3c \cdot x_2 &= f(x_2,y_2) \\
-3b \cdot y_2 &= g(x_2,y_2)
\end{align}
We can therefore take any change of variable $x=-2c\cdot x_2+b\cdot y_2, y=c\cdot x_2-2b\cdot y_2$, as long as it is invertible. For example if we take $b=c=1$ we get $x=-2x_2+y_2, y=x_2-2y_2$.
Usually though, finding an eigensystem is easier.
EDIT: for people more familiar with linear algebra:
We have a system of equations $A\vec{x}$ and are searching for a change of coordinates $\vec{x}=B\vec{x'}$, such that $AB\vec{x'} = D'\vec{x'}$, for some diagonal matrix $D'$. We can do this via gaussian elimination of the matrix $A^T$ (and tracking the product of elementary operations), which gives us a matrix $K$, such that $KA^T$ is diagonal. Taking the transpose we get that $AK^T$ is diagonal so $B=K^T$ suffices.

Look up "Gaussian elimination" or "matrix row reduction."

As per OP request I avoided what I think he would consider "computing eigenstuff or determinants or anything involving linear algebra".
